# How can I do an unthethered jailbreak for iPad Wifi running iOS 4.2.1 if you do not have older SHSH?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

How can I jailbreak iOS 4.2.1 (unthethered) if you do not have older SHSH?

Currently I'm looking for this only for my iPad WiFi, so no baseband.

If there are not solutions yet, do not post anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greenpois0n rc5 Has been released and can do an untethered jailbreak on 4.2.1 without older SHSH blobs.

http://www.greenpois0n.com

Comment: Greenpois0n method explained with screencast at http://lifehacker.com/#!5754463

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://lifehacker.com/#!5754463) is a step by step tutorial to do untethered jailbreaking on an iOS 4.2.1 device.

Answer (score 0):

[This how-to guide](http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-ios-4.2.1-untethered-with-redsn0w-0.9.7b1-how-to-guide/) should help.

It's amazing and I used it :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this method requires SHSH from 4.2 beta3, somthing that most people do not have and will never have.

Comment: just google limera1n then -> latest version should really work

Comment: Doesn't support 4.2.1. There is no way to do it without the 4.2b3 shsh blobs yet. It's speculated that greenpois0n RC5 will be able to on Feb 10th.

Comment: It does support 4.2.1!

Comment: limera1n.com WORKS!